# Is it safe to connect AC earth to DC negative?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emc, earth

I'm going to use a switching mode power supply in a product. When I use no earth connection in the input, the metallic body of the PSU gives a little electric shock. (it has ~70V AC with reference from my fingers.) But whenever I connect the earth connection to the input this residual voltage disappears but I still have some residual AC voltage on the DC negative output because the earth connection and DC ground are isolated in the SMPS for some reason I'm trying to understand.

**So the question is: Is it okay to connect the DC negative in the output of the SMPS directly to the AC earth on the input with a small jumper wire to get rid of the residual voltage on the DC negative rail?**

**Edit:** By "OK" I mean passing the safety standards and not tripping the fuse on the consumer side. The product is a walkthrough metal detector and the body is completely floated.

[image: MeanWell LRS-100-24 SMPS]

Block diagram reference: [MeanWell LRS-100-24 datasheet](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/LRS-100/LRS-100-spec.pdf)

According to the datasheet of my SMPS, there is a capacitor from DC negative to earth. I guess the purpose of that cap is to not allow any DC current to flow down to the earth but on the other hand, the DC negative still has some residual voltage even when the earth wire is connected to the input. (~30V AC)

Comment: Have you read the product data sheet to understand what the legal requirements for AC and earth connections are to ensure safety?

Comment: Please clearify what "OK" implies for you. Only from an electrical engineering point of view or safety and regulatory as well? For the latter one would need to know the market and intended use.

Comment: Which power supply make and model it is?

Comment: I'm using MeanWell LRS-100-24 SMPS.

Comment: I wanna make sure it passes the safety standards as well as eliminate the residual voltage on the DC negative rail. The intended application is for a commercial product and the chassis is completely floated.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks it might be a good idea to address the cause of this 'stray' voltage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's okay to connect it (assuming it's otherwise okay to have your supply output grounded). The manufacturer specifies that 'FG' must be grounded in their installation manual for this model.

The purpose of using a capacitor rather than a direct connection is probably to allow freedom to do things like series connection of  power supplies or positive ground (that would otherwise be shorted out).

Comment: `probably to allow freedom to do things like series connection` Unless it's indicated in the datasheet, series connection can't be an option (it's not indicated in the OP's power supply datasheet). Connecting PSUs in series, even though they are of the same series, can be risky.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Depends on the load arrangement. If it's a bipolar supply with loads mostly or entirely to common it's generally not an issue, especially if you add some diodes.

Comment: As you can see, Digikey independently says the exact [same thing](https://forum.digikey.com/t/connecting-mean-well-power-supplies-in-series/19294). Connecting supplies in **parallel** is a much different situation and the datasheet should *explicitly* permit it before it is attempted.

Comment: It requires *you* to place anti-parallel diodes across each output so the PSUs *on their own* can't (or shouldn't) be connected in series. An application note makes this suggestion, so the user may not be aware initially. If you check modular/configurable power supplies you'll see series connection options and they have their own internal anti-parallel diodes and allow direct series connection – require a busbar only. Plus, PSUs with foldback style current limiting (although not that popular or common) may cause some trouble (e.g. lockup) during power on when connected in series.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I agree with that. Anyway, the point is that having the output floating at DC means you *can* do it. It's not possible if you have something like an PC ATX supply with output ground tied hard to earth.

Answer (score 8):

The shock you get comes from the leakage from the chassis.

An offline system having a PE (protective earth) connection and a grounded chassis has capacitors (physical or parasitic) across both L-PE and N-PE (See CY1 and CY2 below). If there's a CM noise (common-mode noise i.e. a noise on both L and N w.r.t. PE) the CM current will flow (partially or fully) through these capacitors to the ground:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffIiaw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the chassis is floating (imagine the mid-point of CY1 and CY2 above is not connected to PE), a small amount of current charges up these internal capacitors to some potential and the chassis will have a non-zero voltage w.r.t both L and N. And once you touch the chassis you'll form a capacitive divider so a current will flow through your body, hence the electric shock you get.

> But whenever I connect the earth connection to the input this residual voltage disappears but I still have some residual AC voltage on the DC negative output because the earth connection and DC ground are isolated in the SMPS for some reason I'm trying to understand.

Some power supplies have their output isolated from the mains (including PE) as illustrated above. The voltage you measure comes from the internal (again, physical or parasitic e.g. CY3 and CY4 above) capacitance(s) between the output terminals and chassis. Designers might have placed capacitors to filter out the CM noise that can be seen on the output.

> Is it okay to connect the DC negative in the output of the SMPS directly to the AC earth on the input with a small jumper wire to get rid of the residual voltage on the DC negative rail?

Electrically, this is usually not a problem. But also depends on the safety class of your power supply. Connecting the DC negative to the PE (protective earth) will eliminate the output CM noise, and is a common practice that can be seen on PC ATX power supplies today, so the entire PC chassis, as well as the port negatives (e.g. USB), are earthed in modern PCs. But note that shorting the DC negative to the PE will (or may) increase the earth leakage current and this may put your equipment out of its safety class (for some equipment, especially medical, the earth leakage current is important). Plus, if you use many of these power supplies on the same line the total earth leakage may become too high to trip the RCD.

---

**EDIT** after OP's edit.

> MeanWell LRS-100-24 datasheet

For this particular power supply, it's okay to short the output negative to the chassis. For most of the PSUs with earthed chassis, it's okay to connect the output negative to the earth.

> I guess the purpose of that cap is to not allow any DC current to flow down to the earth but on the other hand, the DC negative still has some residual voltage even when the earth wire is connected to the input. (~30V AC)

The purpose of that cap is to filter out common-mode noise, as I mentioned above *(For simplification, only one cap might have been shown to indicate the isolation and AC coupling between the output and the earth.)*. Shorting output negative to the chassis will simply eliminate the common-mode noise that possibly appears on the output. It's unclear if the PSUs of the entire LRS-100 series can be connected in series – there's a risk when multiple PSUs are connected in series so the capacitor shouldn't be there to allow series connection/operation.

Comment: When you say "there's a risk when multiple PSUs are connected in series," can you give some information about what the risk is? I would have thought that if you have, say, some 24 V power supplies with a 3,000 V isolation rating, there would be no problem whatsoever with putting a few of those in series (besides the obvious fact that you would end up with a higher voltage than 24 V).

Comment: @TannerSwett Some power supplies are not intended to be connected in series. For example imagine two 12V supplies powering a 24V load, and one supply starts earlier or turns off earlier, have slightly different short circuit limits etc, load or wires get shorted, one supply forces current through the other, as you have essentially connected a +12V supply in parallel with another in reverse.

Comment: @TannerSwett If, for example, two series-connected PSUs turn on to a large capacitive load, and if one's output voltage starts to rise before the other, the latter one will be exposed to a reversed voltage for a relatively longer time. This, though, can be resolved with anti-parallel diodes across each output, but the PSUs advertised as "series operation possible" usually have these diodes internally. `...there would be no problem whatsoever with putting a few of those in series` but if the application requires SELV things would be different.

Comment: Note: capacitors that are used to connect line-side circuits to earth ground must be a special kind of capacitor called a "y-cap". These capacitors fail in very well understood and safe ways, preventing shock hazards. You should also be aware that you will need to pass fcc conducted emissions tests for any product you are bringing to market (or the EU equivalent). The filters needed to reduce unacceptable noise use these same y-caps and will perform much the same function.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is ok to ground the negative output of a open-chassis or enclosed power supply.  Normally this is already done by the mfg to prevent shocks. However there are vintage supplies around were built before NEC standards were enforced.

If you buy a supply built in the last 20 years it will have (possibly) the negative output earth grounded. Even switch-mode and common 50/60 hz transformers have capacitive leakage of 100 pf or more, enough to cause a strong tingle if not grounded. 1 milliamp of current can cause pain to touch, so that would be a serious shock hazard.

Leakage current is limited to 100 microamps for commercial use and 10 microamps for medical grade supplies. These values could change over time.

There are low-cost supplies such as wall-warts/table lamps and cellphone chargers that have no ground pin, yet are certified to not be a shock hazard. They use tricks like double insulation, transformers with side-by-side windings that have very little capacitive leakage, plus use of plastic enclosures so no metal to touch.

Comment: @TimWescott I made a correction. Should have been more loose with the words.

Comment: In my case (MeanWell LRS-100-24) the DC negative is capacitively coupled to the earth. What is the purpose of that capacitor?

Comment: @SajjSamm Switch-mode supplies produce much noise, so capacitors are used in several places to lower EMI to a tolerable level. While not a true Earth gnd, a capacitor to gnd still reduces leakage current.

Answer (score 1):

When using a AC/DC SMPS, the input **should and must be grounded**, as the unit you are using has a metal case. The earth ground on the input is required to stop you getting shocked if and when you come into contact with its casing.
Consumer PSUs like computer chargers and other appliances only have two prongs as they have no metal parts that can be contacted, however your SMPS has a metal case hence protective earth must be used.

For Mean Well supplies, it does not matter whether the V- terminal is connected to PE or left floating. In your case, it is completely fine to connect the V- terminal to mains earth.

Comment: "Consumer PSUs like computer chargers and other appliances only have two prongs..." - I'm not sure if that's a fair analysis - every laptop power supply I've ever seen has a grounded power lead despite not having a metal case. (I'm in the UK, but I believe these power supplies are manufactured for worldwide use, and the question doesn't mention jurisdiction at all.)

Comment: "Consumer PSUs like computer chargers and other appliances only have two prongs" Not true. Maybe where you live. And would likely not apply to Desktop PCs. I don't even understand why anyone would want their computer or monitor to have by design an ungrounded supply that shocks you and damages equipment when hot-plugged together, it simply does not make any sense.

Comment: In the country where I live, most laptop computer chargers and appliances don't have a earth prong-only large desktop computers and high-power devices have a earth prong. If the appliance has metal parts that can be contacted by you, it has an earth prong.